# resultset is closed exception on first iteration of .next()

Tags: java, exception, resultset, cucumber-jvm

i cant figure out why my resultset is throwing the exception.. 
Resultset object is not null in debugging, however it cannot enter the if statement if(resultset.next())
I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong..
Thanks for any help.

by the way, i'm accessing this class through a cucumber test, however at this stage i dont think thats relevant to the problem..

Here is the relevant code:

```
 input = new Object[]{nEventID, nEventID, nAccountID};
 callback = new NamedQueryStatementCallback("GET_ACTIVE_EVENT_ENTITLEMENT_DETAILS",     input, false);
 resultSet = (ResultSet)getHibernateTemplate().execute(callback);

 if (resultSet != null)
 {
outputList = new ArrayList();
if (resultSet.next()) //here is where exception gets thrown - on first iteration,     so it never enters branch
{
    do
    {
        //create object list with data
    }while (resultSet.next());
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is this is either using Spring 2 or some proprietary fork of it. The [API doc for the HibernateTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html#execute%28org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateCallback%29) says:

> Allows for returning a result object, that is a domain object or a
>   collection of domain objects.

Your callback should handle all the processing on the resultSet and populate a domain object, then return the domain object (in this case, objectList). The resultSet gets closed before the call to execute returns.

The point of having callbacks is so that the callback can specify the logic that needs to happen, while the thing executing the callback can manage and clean up resources. ResultSets in particular aren't data holders that can be passed around, they're things that typically need to be used and closed as soon as possible. So I'd expect the framework would close the resultSet once the callback completes.

Comment: Actually the link you posted is from Spring which also implements hibernate. I'm not sure the callback part is relevant to this question.

Comment: @alfasin: it's not clear from the question what the implementation of HibernateTemplate is. But the point of a callback is that it allows code to run while the piece running it can manage resources, so returning a resultSet and accessing it directly after the callback defeats the purpose. so that's why I think it's relevant.

Comment: i just added an if(resultset.isClosed()){//do something} and it blew out there too.. i wonder if this is a casting error? funny, this is not the only place where this exact method of retrieving a resultset has been implemented throughout the code base..

Comment: the difference between this implementation and the others is actually the callback, so i'd say your on the ball nathan

Comment: I'm still at a loss for what to do to fix this.. if somebody can point me in a direction

Comment: @user1359079: the objectlist creation code needs to be part of the callback. so you need to create a callback that does that.